# Guice multibinding with named binding

Tags: java, guice, java-17

I have a bunch of Processor. Some are of the same object type but have different configuration. I want to create a set of processor but choose which processor should go in which set. If there a way to do that using multibinding?

```java
public class PostProcessorModule extends AbstractModule {

    public static final String TYPE_A = "TypeA";
    public static final String TYPE_B = "TypeB";

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        Multibinder<PostProcessor> typeASet =
            Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), PostProcessor.class, Names.named("TypeASet"));
        typeASet.addBinding().to(RandomizationPostProcessor.class);  // Only want Type A 
here
        typeASet.addBinding().to(SecondPostProcessor.class);

        Multibinder<PostProcessor> typeBSet =
            Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), PostProcessor.class, Names.named("TypeBSet"));
        typeASet.addBinding().to(RandomizationPostProcessor.class);  // Only want Type B 
here
        typeASet.addBinding().to(SecondPostProcessor.class);
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(TYPE_A)
    public RandomizationPostProcessor getRandomizationPostProcessorA() {

        return RandomizationPostProcessor.builder()
                   .toRandomize(3)
                   .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(TYPE_B)
    public RandomizationPostProcessor getRandomizationPostProcessorB() {

        return RandomizationPostProcessor.builder()
                   .toRandomize(10)
                   .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public SecondPostProcessor getSecondPostProcessor() {

        return new SecondPostProcessor();
    }
}

public class Test {
    @Inject
    @Named("TypeASet")
    private final Set<PostProcessor> setA;
    
    @Inject
    @Named("TypeBSet")
    private final Set<PostProcessor> setB;

    public void doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}
```

`RandomizationPostProcessor` and `SecondPostProcessor` implements `PostProcessor`.

Does multibinding support this? I can't see any function like `annotatedWith` or similar which we have in normal `bind()` function. Is writing another function the only way to create custom set?

Comment: You probably want to use `multibinder.addBinding().toInstance(x)` instead.

The `Names.named(...)` you're adding to the multibinder determine how the multibinder itself is bound, not how values are added to the multibinder.

Comment: Updated question to show what i want in the end by injecting into a consuming class.

Comment: Yes, but since you're putting these into a set, how are you going to have multiple `@Provides` methods with the `@Named(TYPE_B) RandomizationPostProcessor` signature? Guice will complain about something with that signature already being bound.

If you need to add multiple values of a given type, typically you add those to a Multibinder using `addBinding().toInstance(...)`.

Comment: You are adding to `typeASet` four times. You probably want `typeBSet` for the second two. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can `addBinding` to a specific key:

```
typeASet.addBinding().to(Key.get(RandomizationPostProcessor.class, Names.named(TYPE_A))
typeBSet.addBinding().to(Key.get(RandomizationPostProcessor.class, Names.named(TYPE_B))
```